# Как проверить существование определённого индекса в массиве?

Tags: javascript

Есть массив, индексы в котором не от 0 и до ..., а могут быть совершенно любые: 1, 4, 10, 1356, при этом в массиве всего четыре элемента, но вот с такими индексами. Как проверить существует ли в массиве индекс, например, 10?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130931/discussion-on-question-by-slider11-----).

Answer (score 1):

```
const arr = [1, , 3, 76, , , 34, ];

for(let i in arr) {
  console.log(i + ':' +arr[i]);
}
```

Может это поможет

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

В таком случае лучше использовать объект или Map, потому что массивы с непоследовательными индексами в JS работают неоптимально и это противоречит их назначению. Но если без этого не обойтись, можно использовать оператор `in`:

```js
const array = [];

array[10] = 'foo';

console.log(0 in array); // false

console.log(10 in array); // true
```